# can't pass value to next UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I created a new UIViewController class including a xib file in xcode 6.
I set up everything like so

.h file next ViewController

```
@interface NextViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,assign) int gameID;

@end
```

.m file next ViewController

```
@synthesize gameID;
```

.m file previous View Controller

```
NextViewController *nextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
nextViewController.gameID = -1;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
```

when I ran it through the debugger the `gameID` is set in the .h file but when I want to access the value in the `viewDidLoad` method I get `0` for `gameID` instead of `-1`

Comment: `[nextViewController setGameID:-1]`?

Comment: @JAL dot syntax is just syntactic sugar for that. It's the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems perfectly fine & it should work as expect a.k.a should rint "-1" in `-(void) viewDidLoad`.
Another approach I can think of is to try with overriding `-init` method like following:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil withGameId:(int)gameIdParam {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.gameID = gameIdParam;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Declare this method in `.h` file & then use this method to create new instance of your `NextViewController`with passing `gameID` as a parameter.

Please note that, your code is itself correct. I tried it on Mac & it's working fine.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work, I used the same kind of method in the same project and it works! but overriding the -init method worked...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the viewDidLoad is getting hit before you set the GameID.  Try setting a breakpoint on viewDidLoad and on nextViewController.gameID = -1; to see which one gets hit first.  You can override the setter for gameID to perform logic based off of it if that is the case.

Comment: they are called in the way i want it to first nextViewController.gameID = -1 then into nextViewController .h file where i can see that it is set right and after that the viewDidLoad method is called...